# Update table with data from a second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with the following columns:

```
ID, title
```

I need to update every title cell in this table with the title value from another table that has this structure:

```
ID, attribute, value
```

The problem being that table 2 above could have any number of attribute types (title, location, url), and I only want the title attribute copied. I have tried the following but it fails:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.title = table2.value
where table2.attribute='title' and table1.ID = table2.ID;
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use join

```
UPDATE table1 t
JOIN table2 t2 ON t.ID = t2.ID
SET t.title = t2.value
WHERE t2.attribute='title';
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! (once I turned off the pref that was only allowing safe update mode for tables like this without a key)